# How do we separate the component of specific type in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods

i am beginner at Java. That's why, i need to get some help.
Firstly, we have a specific type class called Box and its code:

```
public class Box {
private String content;

public Box(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public boolean isOperator() {
    if (content.matches("\\-?\\d+")) {
        return false;
    } else if (content.equals("*") || content.equals("/") || content.equals("+") || content.equals("-")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isOperand() {
    return !isOperator();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" + content + "}";
}
```

}

And there are converter classes which create boxes, for example:

`"3,+,5" => convert() =>{"3"}{"+"}{"5"}` comma is used for separator character

In main method, when I invoke the code below, how do we do separate the operations?

```
Converter converter = new Converter("3,+,*,2,/,4,-,7");
    ArrayList<Box> list = converter.convert();
```

Comment: can you guarentee there is only one character between each comma?

Comment: if (list.get(0).getContent().equals("3") && list.get(1).getContent().equals("+")...)

Comment: When i use the if statement above, it must be true.

Comment: `list.get(1)` will give you a comma !

Comment: Are you asking about how to implement the `convert` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this:

```
public static List<Box> convert(String valueToConvert) {
    List<Box> boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
    for(String value : Arrays.asList(valueToConvert.split(","))) {
        boxList.add(new Box(value));
    }
    return boxList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each character is guaranteed to have a comma after it before the next one:

```
char[] characters = whateverString.toCharArray();
// characters[0] is first character, characters[1] is comma
// characters[2] is second character, characters[3] is comma
// and so on
// characters.length has the number of characters (including commas)
```

Comment: what if one of the numbers is 12?